# Обращение к option через jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

В общем есть такая проблема, остался последний штрих сайта и с ним я на долго завис, на сайте использую jQuery. Если знаете как правильно будет обратится r элементом value="4, то буду благодарен.

```
 <div class="form-select">
    <select id="my_select">
        <option value="1">Завтра</option>
        <option value="2">Послезавтра</option>
        <option value="3">Через 2 дня</option>
        <option value="4">Своя дата</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

И сам код jQuery

```
$("#my_select [value='4']").on('click', function(e) {
  $('.order-form-item-hour2').toggleClass('order-form-item-hour2_active');
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Если знаете как правильно будет обратится r элементом value="4

События для `select` это изменения (change), а `click` это для кнопок.

---

Можно так обратиться:

```js
$("#my_select").on('change', function(e) {
  if ($(this).val() === '4') { //<---- Вот так
    console.log($(this).val());
    $('.order-form-item-hour2').toggleClass('order-form-item-hour2_active');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-select">
  <select id="my_select">
    <option value="1">Завтра</option>
    <option value="2">Послезавтра</option>
    <option value="3">Через 2 дня</option>
    <option value="4">Своя дата</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Просто огромное спасибо)

Comment: Можешь сказать зачем тут используется change

Comment: @ИванТрушко если помогло отметить галочку. События для `select` это изменения, а `click` это для кнопок.

Comment: Я на этом сайте недавно, скажи как)